# Про качество набора данных при обучении нейронной сети

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Подскажите, пожалуйста, будет ли помехой (повлияет ли это на **точность** / на что-либо), если на всех картинках обучающего набора **в углу каждой картинки** будет одна и та же **ссылка** на сайт? Использую модель YoloV3, алгоритм Object Detection и целевые метки будут на котов. То-есть выделять буду котов.

Как на фото снизу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, она не ухудшит метрику заметным образом. Во-первых, потому что метки всё равно стоят на котах(если, опять же, ссылки не залезают на котов слишком часто), а во-вторых, потому что ссылки имеют очень маленькую площадь и располагаются в одном месте. Единственная проблема может возникнуть, только если вы попробуете находить котов на изображениях без ссылок, но и там нужно уже будет смотреть по ходу исследования.

ЗАПОМНИТЕ, небольшие аномалии в данных - больше хорошо, чем плохо, потому что они способствуют предотвращению переобучаемости модели(но это правило будет работать только при достаточно большом размере выборки).

Comment: здравствуйте, спасибо!